# Getting contents of localhost using winsock

Tags: c, winsock

Hey! I am trying to connect to my localhost and the index page I have there. But every time I try I just get:

```
Dados -> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2009 15:25:41 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.10 (Win32) PHP/5.2.8 Content-Length: 226 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>400 Bad Request</title> </head><body> <h1>Bad Request</h1> <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br /> </p> </body></html>
```

☺

Here is the code I have:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main()
{
    WSADATA WsaDat;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&WsaDat)!=0)
    {
        printf("Winsock error - Winsock initialization failed\r\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(Socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Winsock error - Socket creation Failed!\r\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }


    struct hostent *host;
    if((host=gethostbyname("localhost"))==NULL)      
    {
        printf("Failed to resolve hostname.\r\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Resolveu o hostname\r\n");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port= htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family= AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr= *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr))!=0)
    {
        printf("Failed to establish connection with server\r\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    char get[] = {
                    "GET / HTTP/1.1\n"
                    "From: bla@ble\n"
                    "User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0\n"
                    "\n"
                };
    send(Socket,get, strlen(get),0);


    printf("Ligou-se\r\n");
    char buffer[1000];
    int nDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,1000,0);
    printf("Dados -> %s",buffer);


    shutdown(socket,SD_SEND);


    closesocket(socket);

    WSACleanup();



    return 0;
}
```

Is there something missing? I am following a tutorial and that's basically the code they have there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4) requires a `Host: localhost` header - either add this or use HTTP 1.0

Also, headers are separated by `\r\n`, not just `\n`.

Comment: Thanks! It's working for the localhost but not for other sites (like for this one) Going to try and read a little more about http.

Answer (score 0):

As RoBorg said your get string should be:

```
    char get[] = {
                "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                "Host: localhost\r\n"
                "From: bla@ble\r\n"
                "User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0\r\n"
                "\r\n"
            };
```

If you are connecting to other sites besides localhost the 'host' field will have to be updated (usually hostname, IP address, or www works).

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to try just using HTTP/1.0, which you don't need to specify the extra values:

char get[] = {
                    "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                };

Should work everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try using **WinInet** for your client-side Http needs instead of just sockets.

Lots of people connect to web services through proxies -- that is, their own computer can't access the web, but it can get to a nearby computer (the proxy) that will forward the request on.  You socket code doesn't handle proxies, but the WinInet API will do it for you automatically.

[As an old-fashioned networking person, I loath these devices -- they've essentially badly implemented routers]

Similarly, you might want to switch your server to https: some day; you'll have a heck of a time updating your socket code to handle this, but again, WinInet does it for you.

[Note: I work at Microsoft]